# Send a table inside of RTF message JavaMail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send a email with  a Table in string with RTF, but when I check the email the message body, the table lost the format, so I wondering what I'm doing wrong, this is the following chunk of code to send and email

```java
public static void send(String asunto, String texto, String emailDestinatario){
    final String username = "myemail@gmail.com";
    final String password = "mypass";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse( emailDestinatario));
        message.setSubject(asunto);
        message.setText(texto);

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

what others configurations  I need to send and email and recogniz me the format of table?

This is a document [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/171mq8i6wsoa3fz/table_email.odt?dl=0) to send via email

I get something like that(the table lost the format)

```
TARIFAS EMPLEADOS
TARIFA
IVA
TOTAL
EMPLEADOS HASTA $150.000.000
94,000
15,040
109,040
EMPLEADOS MAYOR DE $150.000.000
160,000
25,600
185,600
```

Comment: Where is the RTF? You seem to be sending a simple string. You are not setting content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have  you tried something like :

```
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(sesion);  
    .
    .
    .
    //Config your message....

    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    htmlPart.setContent("RTF HTML TEXT", "text/html");

    mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);           
    message.setContent(mp);

    Transport.send(message);
```